# Problemas con el item listener del JCheckBox

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy usando este código para hacer legible la clave ingresada en el JPasswordfield "jp_clave" al chequear el JCheckBox "jcb_clave"

```
private void jcb_claveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    jcb_clave.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            jp_clave.setEchoChar((char) 0);  

        } else {
            jp_clave.setEchoChar('*');

        }
    }
});
```

El problema es que al ejecutar el programa tengo que chequear y des chequear el JCheckBox por primera vez para que funcione como debe, talvez sea algún error tonto así que les pido que me tengan paciencia y me ayuden por favor.

EDITADO

Al parecer le estaba dando muchas vueltas al código y gracias a TwoDent mi dilema esta resuelto, respecto al código del JPasswordField:

```
jp_clave = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();    

jp_clave.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
jp_clave.setText("");
```

Es todo lo que pude rastrear ya que se genero el código automáticamente cuando arrastre el componente en el formulario, por defecto todo texto que se escriba en el pasa a ser como si se ingresase una contraseña y el código en el checkbox (si se esta chequeado) obligaba a mostrar el texto tal cual lo tipeaste

Comment: Que exactamente es el comportamiento del JPasswordField despues de crearlo y que comportamiento esperas? Puedes compartir el código donde lo creas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque no intentas con esto:

```
if(MiCheckBox.isSelected()){
    //mis acciones
}
```

Osea, en tu caso:

```
if(jcb_clave.isSelected()){
   jp_clave.setEchoChar((char)0);
}
```

La funcion `isSelected()` verifica si tu checkbox esta activado o no.